# Java runtime getInputStream ignores majority of terminal command output

Tags: java, runtime, inputstream, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a Java program to capture the output of a terminal command. Under "normal" conditions, i.e. where I execute the command directly into the terminal myself, I can see the following result:

[image]

However, the output rendered by my Java program only captures a small subset of that, see here:

[image]

This is the codebase I'm speaking of:

```
import java.io.*;

class evmTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String evmResult = "";

        String evmCommand = "evm --debug --code 7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020101 run";
        try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec(evmCommand);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                evmResult += inputLine;
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Thus far I've not been able to determine why that code is only able to emit the paltry `0x`. I've posted this question in the hopes that someone might be able to help me track down the cause of this error.

Answer (score -1):

do it like this:

```
import java.io.*;

class evmTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String evmResult = "";

    String evmCommand = "evm --debug --code 7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020101 run";
    try {

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String command = "evm --debug --code 7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020101 run";
        Process proc = rt.exec(command);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You need to read these streams in separate threads, or merge them.